# How can I prove that RGB color space is or is not an Orthogonal Transformation?

Tags: vector-spaces, orthogonal-matrices

I was searching a lot of information about **Color Space** and how can I prove that the RGB color space is or not Orthogonal Transform, I suppose that it's Orthogonal Transform because all the image of this color space that I saw, it show like a cube, but I found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space#Conversion_2) that I can express any color space with the reference standard **CIE-XYZ** and I found here the matrix transform for this two space [here](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html) but those matrix are not Orthogonal, so I don't know how is the correct answer.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How are you turning the color space into a vector space? It seems unclear to me how this can be done in a meaningful way.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Sorry I'm not familiar enough to this concepts, but I think that the professor was talking about the matrix to transform from one color space to another color space, I sent an email to him and he told me that I need the matrix operations to prove this.

Comment: According to this paper the transform matrix between RGB and CIE-XYZ varies based on display so if it's an orthogonal matrix I expect it's the result of the normalization process during it's construction. https://poynton.ca/PDFs/coloureq.pdf

Comment: Thank you, you were right. @CyclotomicField